# Even though I registered an environment variable, it says that the so file cannot be loaded. What should I do?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, dex

When I tried to use dexdump, but the so file could not be loaded, I registered the path of the file as an environment variable, but the same error occurred no matter how many times I repeated it. What should I do?

```
muang@ubuntu:~/Desktop/dataset/dexdump2$ 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/Desktop/dataset/dexdump2/obj
muang@ubuntu:~/Desktop/dataset/dexdump2$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
muang@ubuntu:~/Desktop/dataset/dexdump2$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/Desktop/dataset/dexdump2/obj
muang@ubuntu:~/Desktop/dataset/dexdump2$ ./dexdump2 
./dexdump2: error while loading shared libraries: libdexfile.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The above is what it appeared when running on Ubuntu Terminal.

If you know how to solve it, please reply.

Comment: Just a guess but I think LD_LIBRARY_PATH should be set to $HOME/Desktop/dataset/dexdump2/obj, not /Desktop/dataset/dexdump2/obj.

Comment: @Jeff Holt I thought so at first, so I tried it and it shouldn't. There is no desktop through home, but a desktop directory.

Comment: Your prompt indicates your current working directory is ~/Desktop/dataset/dexdump2, hence my guess (because ~ is short for $HOME in some contexts). I suggest you edit your post to include the output of `ls -la /Desktop/dataset/dexdump2/obj`.

Comment: @Jeff Holt 

I first thought that ["$" HOME] was the shell prompt, so I just tried typing HOME, but after reading Ripple again, I added $ HOME and tried it !!! Thank you very much. ~ Is that $ HOME was omitted !!